# AttributeError at /logout/ 'tuple' object has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: python-3.x, django, ldap

I used Python3 in windows 10 to write a django2 web app.
I tried to configure the LDAP login, but failed.
When I test using postman, it could get the reply successfully.
That is, I send a request to https://example.com/staff, with some authentication code and payload containing username and password, and it reply me with the LDAP reply.

However, when I tried to using ldap3 in Django, after successfully login, error shows:

```
AttributeError at /logout/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

code:
settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'app.backends.LDAPBackend',
('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'),
)
```

app/backends.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model    
UserModel = get_user_model()

class LDAPBackend:

def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):

    try:      
        headers = {'Authorization': xxxxx}        
        body = {"username": username, "password": password}    
        response = requests.post(url="https://example.com/staff", json=body, headers=headers)
        result = response.json()
        print(result)     
        if result['code'] != "OK":

            logger.info("Wrong Login Information")
            return None
        print("connected")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    user = UserModel.objects.update_or_create(username=username)
    return user

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

error shows: AttributeError at /logout/ 'tuple' object has no attribute 'backend', below shows result in console:

```
   connected
Internal Server Error: /logout/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 61, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 382, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 409, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 205, in clean
    self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\software\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 80, in authenticate
    user.backend = backend_path
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'backend'
[22/Mar/2021 09:49:10] "POST /logout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 149071
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the following line:

```
user = UserModel.objects.update_or_create(username=username)
```

The `update_or_create` method returns a tuple with the object and a boolean with whether the object was created. So you are storing this tuple in the variable `user` and returning that. But `authenticate` is supposed to return only the user causing unintended effects leading to an error. Also you should be using [`get_or_create` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) instead of `update_or_create`.

So you should change that above line to:

```
user, created = UserModel.objects.get_or_create(username=username)
```